# laravel addEagerConstraints on hasOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Experiencing some Laravel issues here.

I've got 3 models:

**notification**

- id
- message
- sender_id
- recipient_id
- etc..

**participant**

- id
- user_id
- etc..

**user**

- id
- name
- etc..

A notification can have a sender (sender_id) and a recipient (recipient_id) both referencing to the participant table.
A participant has a reference to user (user_id).

I'm trying to fetch a list of notifications with both sender and recipient with code below.

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant', 'sender_id', 'id')->with(['user']);
}

public function recipient()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant', 'id', 'recipient_id')->with(['user']);
}
```

This returns empty result
    [relations:protected] => Array
        (
            [sender] => 
            [recipient] => 
        )

When changing the code to:

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant', 'sender_id', 'id')->with(['user'])->first();
}

public function recipient()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant', 'id', 'recipient_id')->with(['user'])->first();
}
```

I'm getting a

> "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()"

Comment: First of all, why do you have 2 functions for recipient() ?

Comment: Made a mistake, i've corrected the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relationships are not setup correctly. Since the `notifications` table has the foreign keys (`sender_id` and `recipient_id`), it is said that the `Notification` belongs to the `Participant`, and the `Participant` has one or many `Notification`s.

You need to update your relationship on the `Notification` model to be `belongsTo` relationships:

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
}

public function recipient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Participant::class);
}
```

A couple notes:

1. Since you didn't show your participant/user relationship, make sure that it is defined as "a participant belongs to a user, a user has one or many participants". That is how your database is setup.
2. The error you were getting in your second attempt ("Call to undefined method") is because relationship methods must return a `Relation` instance. By calling `first()`, you were actually executing the query and returning a `Model`, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, keep your models cleaner and just write the relationship logic there.

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant');
}
public function recipient()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Participant');
}
```

Now, in your controller, you write the logics:

```
$sender = YourModel::sender()->where('sender_id', $id)->first();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Tanvir, not quite following you here.
The Participant modal has no sender_id. The notification modal does; as a reference to the participant modal.

Regarding the cleaner modals: If would need a list of notifications with both sender as recipient i'd probably want this right:
Notification::with([ 'sender', 'recipient'])?
In this case i would expect my modal also to be correct.